Не могу найти нужный параметр в promoteChatMember Aiogram 3.x
Я хочу сделать команду, которая будет выдавать пользователю администратора, но только должность(внизу картинка). И я не понимаю какой параметр за это отвечает.

await bot.promote_chat_member(chat_id="-1002188466387", user_id={message.reply_to_message.from_user.id})

await bot.set_chat_administrator_custom_title(chat_id='id чата', 
                                              user_id=123, 
                                              custom_title='Новое название')

Метод set_chat_administrator_custom_title() позволяет менять название "должности" пользователя. Имеет 3 обязательных аргумента, которые представлены в коде выше. В случае успеха возвращает True.
Документация:

https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/api/methods/set_chat_administrator_custom_title.html#setchatadministratorcustomtitle
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setchatadministratorcustomtitle


Спасибо огромное!

Отметьте ответ как правильный, если помог.
